# NHibernate Criteria for a non-linked table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

We are adding an attribute(tags) to a system.  The attribute table is just a relation table without any foreign keys. 
 Is there a way to add to the criteria to generate a where clause for the attribute table on a parent table.

```
<class name="Account" table="dbo.Account" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id" column="`AccountId`">
        <generator class="int"/>    
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="`Name`" />
    <property name="Address" column="`Address`" />
</class>

<class name="Attribute" table="dbo.Attribute" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id" column="`AttributeId`">
        <generator class="int"/>    
    </id>   
    <property name="Name" column="`Name`" />
    <property name="LinkId" column="`LinkId`" />
    <property name="Type" column="`Type`" />
</class>
```

Example Data

```
Account
1 - Person - Address
2 - Person - Address

Attribute
1 - Attrib1 - 1 - Account
2 - Attrib2 - 1 - Account
3 - Attrib1 - 2 - Account
4 - Attrib1 - 3 - Event
5 - Attrib1 - 4 - Location
```

Sample of Existing Code

```
ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Account));
crit.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", "Some"););
```

I would like to add the following to the where clause.

```
AccountId IN (SELECT LinkId FROM Attribute WHERE Name = 'Attrib1')
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'a relation table without foreign keys' ?

Comment: The linkId in attribute table is the primary key from the table defined in the type field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you using an `any` type mapping for this? it does exactly this: referencing by a primary key and type name...

There might be some mistakes in the following piece of code, but it looks something like this:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<Attribute>()
  .Add(Projections.Property("LinkId"))
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", "Attrib1"))
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Type", typeof(Account)));


ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Account));
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", "Some"))
  .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("id", subquery));
```

Comment: .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn(expression.PropertyName, criteria)) was the correct syntax on that item.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this was a typo, I fixed it.